# opencart admin login No Error No Login

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

i have running opencart for months now never have an issue since yesterday when i try to login to admin it does not show any error but stay on admin page. with these 2 request

http://mywebsite.com/admin/index.php?route=common/login

http://mywebsite.com/admin/index.php?route=common/login&token=c68f8306024feb01cac3ba1814a61a80

I am using windows. I've checked error.txt nothing there. Have no idea where to go from here

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems. Do you have slow_log enabled in MySQL's my.cnf? If so, check the size of the log and the free space on the server (when the slow log takes up all the free space things go nasty with OC).